# How to validate the last character in a capture group with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I want to extract the path out of a URL and I want to use regex for it.

I'm using this regex:
`^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\n\?\=ֿ\#]+)`

and one side effect that the last `/` is captured.

e.g. -

```
domain.com/home/ = domain.com/home/
domain.com/home?param=value = domain.com/home
```

how do I validate that the last character of a specific capture group is not `/`?

**note** - I know I can solve this with another regex match, but I assume it can be done with one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your last match non-greedy followed by an optional `/`. Then make sure that is followed by a `?` or end:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\n?=ֿ#]+?)\/?(?=\?|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iwLM6h/1)

Your group #1 will stop a position before last `/` assuming URL ends with that or there is a query string afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

One way could be adding the `/` to the negated character class to not match it, and only match it when it is followed by any char other than `/` or a whitespace char.

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?((?:[^:\n?=ֿ#\/]+|\/(?=[^\s\/])[^:\n?=ֿ#\/]*)*)
```

The last part will match

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[^:\n?=ֿ#\/]+` Match any char except the listed including `/`
    - `|` Or
    - `\/(?=[^\s\/])` match `/` when directly followed by any char other then `/` or a whitespace char
    - `[^:\n?=ֿ#\/]*` Match optional chars other than the listed
  - `)*` Close non capture group and repeat 0+ times to match multiple `/`
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qDbLVF/1)